# How to make a button in OpenGL c++ with imgui

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, button, imgui

I want to know how to make buttons in OpenGL c++ with glfw. I know how to make a button and text box in OpenGL but I have one problem. When I make a button on the top of the imgui, there is a window like rectangle that has a name(imgui demo, or any name you name it) I want to remove that. And can I blend the color in so the OpenGL window and imgui window look the same. Just remove the top part and blend color.

[image: Imgui buttons]

As you can see in the image everything is the same expect the top part. I want to fix that, or remove it.

Comment: I know how to fix the top window but not the bottom right grey shade. To fix the top part just need to click the arrow but I dont know for the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use any of the Window creation flags

```
ImGuiWindowFlags flags = ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove
                         | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoDecoration
                         | ImGuiWindowFlags_AlwaysAutoResize
                         | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoSavedSettings;

if(transparent) flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoBackground;

ImGui::Begin("##name", nullptr, flags);
{

... buttons widget etc..

}
ImGui::End();
```

Please refer the imgui_demo.cpp. It got everything possible with imgui